# Move childhtml from product/view.phtml to product/view/description.phtml

Tags: xml, magento, layout, block

under my theme's config.xml, below my config.xml files `<catalog_product_view>`  used to trigger product reviews and it's form.

```
  <catalog_product_view translate="label">
      <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>

  <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
          <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/productpageprice.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>    

      <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
      <reference name="root">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
      <reference name="head">
          <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
          <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

          <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
      </reference>
      <reference name="content">
          <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
              <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
              <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                  <label>Alert Urls</label>
              </block>

      <block type="review/product_view_list" name="review.list" as="review_list" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
          <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
            <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
            <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
          </block>
        </block>
      </block>

              <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

              <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                  <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                  <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>20</limit></action>
              </block>

      <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.short_des_after" as="short_des_after" translate="label">
                  <label>Product View Short Description After</label>
              </block>

              <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
              <block type="core/template" name="product.info.additonal_collateral" as="product_additional_collateral" template="catalog/product/view/additional_collateral.phtml" translate="label">
                  <label>Add Extra Tabs of Collateral</label>
              </block>

                  <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
              </block>
              <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                  <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
              </block>



      <!-- Custom -->

      <block type="catalog/product_view_inthebox" name="product.inthebox" as="inthebox" template="catalog/product/view/inthebox.phtml">
                  <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
              </block>

      <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <!-- added -->
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="review.list" as="review_list" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
              <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                  <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                  <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
              </block>
            </block> 
      </block>

              <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addtoproductview.phtml"/>
      <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocartproductview.phtml"/>
      <!-- Custom -->

              <!--<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>-->

              <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                  <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
              </block>

              <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                  <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                  <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                  <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
              </block>
                      <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                  </block>
              <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                  <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                  <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                  <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
              </block>

              <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                  <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                  <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
              </block>
              <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                  <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                  <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                  <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
              </block>
              <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
              <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>

      <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
      <block type="catalog/product_price" name="catalog.product.price" template="catalog/product/productpageprice.phtml"/>

    </block>
      </reference>

      <reference name="right">
          <!--block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/-->
      </reference>

  </catalog_product_view>
```

and using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>` in my themes `product/view.phtml` to display review with review form.

Now i'm trying to use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>` in `product/view/description.phtml` but it's showing empty.

Any solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open **magento\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\catalog.xml**

find

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>

</block>
```

replace above "**catalog/product_view_description**" with below one

```
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
     ........
     <reference name="content">
     ......
      <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                        <!-- added-->
                        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="review.list" as="review_list" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                          <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                              <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                              <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                            </block>
                          </block>
                        </block>
                        <!-- added -->
    </block>
.....
</reference name="content">
..............
</catalog_product_view>
```

and in **magento\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\view\description.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>
```

hope this help you

Comment: Awesome you are !! it worked, but one small bug after updating catalog.xml description tab on product page appearing twice ?

Comment: before catalog.xml which xml you used?

Comment: no i didn't made any changes except catalog.xml under my current activated theme

Comment: please can you post your </catalog_product_view> handle?

Comment: Complete </catalog_product_view> handle? updated in question.

Comment: remove block "review/product_view_list" out side "catalog/product_view_description" block i.e. 1st one:)